# Why $http response data are not shown in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a example of directive in  angular js .I am using this directive
https://github.com/ONE-LOGIC/ngFlowchart

when I take static data ..it show the output please check my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/d2hAhkFG0oN3HPBRS9UU?p=preview

but when I use $http request and make same json object .it not display the chart see my plunker using $http request .I have same data object as in static

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vts6GdT0NNudZr2SJgVY?p=preview

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        var arr = data
        var model={};

        var new_array = []
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = arr[i].name;
            obj.id = arr[i].id;
            obj.x = arr[i].x;
            obj.y = arr[i].y;
            obj.color = '#000';
            obj.borderColor = '#000';
            var p = {};
            p.type = 'flowchartConstants.bottomConnectorType';
            p.id = arr[i].con_id
            obj.connectors = [];
            obj.connectors.push(p);
            new_array.push(obj);

        }
        console.log('new array')
        console.log(new_array)
          model.nodes=new_array;


        var edge = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].children.length > 0) {

                for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].children.length; j++) {
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.source = arr[i].con_id;
                    obj.destination = arr[i].children[j].con_id;
                    edge.push(obj);
                }

            }

        }
          model.edges=edge;
        console.log(edge)
        console.log("model")
          console.log(JSON.stringify(model))
          $scope.flowchartselected = [];
      var modelservice = Modelfactory(model, $scope.flowchartselected);

    $scope.model = model;
    $scope.modelservice = modelservice;

    })
```

any update ?

Comment: According to the Plunkr, your data is not found. Response code is 404 and response is:
`{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": "Not Found"
}`
Since you only provide a `.success()` (which, by the way, is deprecated, consider switching to `.then()`), you can't catch the error.

Comment: Sorry i will update my plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vts6GdT0NNudZr2SJgVY?p=preview

Comment: I'm looking into it, it may take a bit to fully understand the code before I can see the error.

Comment: I look both object ..both are same ..see updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Vts6GdT0NNudZr2SJgVY?p=preview

Comment: got the solution thanks for help http://plnkr.co/edit/d2hAhkFG0oN3HPBRS9UU?p=preview

Comment: Gratz! Please write up the solution as an answer and accept if you would so kindly. And happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ClbKpyTENqVr11am9UFy?p=preview)

It is now working.

The issue was when we load the directive first time it has no parameter value to it. So, when the chart directive try to initialize your chart with no parameter it gets an error. So, it will not work anymore.

**How solve the issue?**

Just give a dummy parameter upon the page load. I have given the dummy model as,

```
 $scope.model = model;
 $scope.modelservice = modelservice;
```

So, first your chart will display a chart based on the dummy values. After that it populates chart with the data from the server (`$http.get()`)